# React Native & Android?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm contemplating on using React Native for a new web app. Is it possible to ship both iOS and Android apps using it?

I know that it's on the roadmap, but it's unclear to me whether it's going to be a separate open-source project (e.g., React Android vs React Native), or just one (e.g., React Native).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**TLDR**: Most likely you can. But it depends on your use cases.

You can aim for about **80~99+% code reuse** (depending on how much Android/iOS native views/modules you use eg. Do you have custom graphics code or low-level TCP networking code; Those can only be done in native code; And expose as API to your JS code. The amount of the platform-specific JS code is actually minimal. Plus you can also use platform check like `if (Platform.OS === 'android'){}` to solve that) of code reuse, which is pretty nice. Dropbox and other companies have done similar projects: using c++ to build a 'shared' component between iOS and Android project, while implementing most of the UI code in native iOS(Objective-c or swift) and Android(java). But now you are doing C++ with Java and Objective-C or Swift, more language to master, more complexity and more brain juice went down the drain. And it probably took some super tough gymnastic move to make different native code work in both iOS and Android, plus debugging...

React Native just makes it **a lot easier to write almost everything in JavaScript**. But there is a catch, only about 80% of the JS code could be shared. In the foreseeable future, you still need to write 'platform-specific' JS code for Android and iOS versions.

That's why FB said they aim for **'Learn once, code anywhere'** instead of 'run' everywhere.

But it's still very nice other than code reuse(**80+% code reuse** is still a big improvement comparing to maintaining 2 entirely different versions: Android and iOS ya?)

**Cmd +R to refresh the app is a GREAT boost for development speed.** Waiting for a big project to compile just makes you felt you were dying inside.

**Declarative UI you get for free, because of using React. This is another great plus!** As you don't need to 'dig' into your specific UI code that often anymore. Data changed? Just 'flush' it and UI just update accordingly. No brain juice wasted.

I **just ported my not so complicated Android React Native App to iOS**. And it took me **3 days**. The request for and iOS version for the App came as a rather abrupt and unplanned move. So could definitely be even faster had I built the Android with a plan for iOS too. **Huge win:)**

Another great benefit is able to do **hot code push** without going through the hellish 1 week app store review process. So no more, "YAY, our app is approved. Let's release. Oh Shiiit. Critical bug and our app keeps crashing(that's gonna keep happening for at least a week before your fix is live). And you have to beg Apple to speed up the process". This is possible because the major part of the code base would be written in JS and with tools like [AppHub](https://apphub.io/) or [CodePush](https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/), you could almost instantly deploy code to your users. This is **conditionally** allowed by Apple.

> 3.3.2 An Application may not download or install executable code. Interpreted code may only be used in an Application if all scripts, code, and interpreters are packaged in the Application and not downloaded. The only exception to the foregoing is scripts and code downloaded and run by Apple's built-in WebKit framework, provided that such scripts and code do not change the primary purpose of the Application by providing features or functionality that are inconsistent with the intended and advertised purpose of the Application as submitted to the App Store.

Lastly, as an open-source project, **project longevity** tends to be a concern. Not an issue for React Native. Internally used by(FB Ads Manager) and backed by FB(a dozen FB Engineers?) by Facebook, with **close to 500 contributors and 25k Stars**, React Native is full of life. Seeing is believing :) (https://github.com/facebook/react-native)

---

**EDIT 1**

I realized that I am apparently a bit **biased and only talked about the good stuff** about React Native. So do checkout https://productpains.com/product/react-native/ and Github issues to have a full picture. It's definitely **not silver bullet**. That being said, it satisfies most of my use case and I couldn't see me use native iOS or Android anytime soon.

**EDIT 2**
The Facebook F8 conference app released by Facebook (duh..) is 100% open source and they have a really nice tutorial to show you how you could have **both** iOS and Android native experience(90% as good as native ?), and at the same time, achieved 85% code re-use. check it out --> **https://makeitopen.com**

**EDIT 3**
You may also want to checkout Flutter and its pros & cons :)

Comment: thanks! I still have yet to get into React Native, but this is reassuring that I have a lot of transferrable skills once I start getting really good at one of the React flavors.

Comment: @williamle8300 glad this helps. I was never a js guy and had been mainly dealing with native android/ios stuffs. My experience with RN was a blast. And if you also gradually realised that most of the devs from RN core team are native mobile devs themselfs:) Plus you are right there are definitely a lot of transferable skills

Comment: Can I write everything in JS? It seems like I'll have to write some c++ or java to get it working?

Comment: @JamieHutber It depends if you need any native module/view. As React Native does not have and does not plan to have official support for 100% of the Android/iOS API, you sometimes need to do some Object-C(iOS) or Java(Android) for your own 'custom modules/vies'. It is also possible that the official API suffice your use case. Then you can write everything in JS.

Comment: Cheers @noooooooob makes things clearer for me to know. Then I just hope that I won't be doing anything too complex, I don't know where that line will be. Close my eyes and jump in is the best approach for me :D

Comment: @JamieHutber  Have fun. There is a good chance that it will be a win:)

Comment: @noooooooob can we use those API,modules written for android and ios specifically, e.g. ccavenue most popular payment gateway of india provide api for android and ios , can we use these while not making app in java ?

Comment: @Amit Bravo     If you are refering to those native modules intended for java and objectivec, yes you can use them. However, you have to writer “wrappers” to expose the API so that your Js code can call them. Check out "native modules" from the doc.

Answer (score 21):

It doesn't make sense to have a single codebase if you want a truly native experience. At the moment we have things like NavigatorIOS in React Native which provides an iOS-style UI for navigating between app screens, but if we were to just start using that on Android it wouldn't feel like a true Android app.

Therefore I'd expect to see a NavigatorAndroid component or similar when the time comes, and the same for various other components that behave differently between the platforms.

One benefit that you would get is that any application logic - maybe a store, or your backend interactions - could be written in a JavaScript file and then included by both iOS and Android.

So while you won't get that write-once run-everywhere developer experience from React Native I would expect to see a solution that gives first-class UI on both platforms while encouraging as much reuse as possible. I personally also hope to see strong build tools to help develop and ship on multiple platforms.

Comment: This is the exact problem I am facing. The application logic and business logic remains the same, but the view logic changes completely across platforms. I guess the main benefit is having developers with the same skill set across platforms

Comment: You can add "real" native component however you want. And at the same time, you could still achieve around 85% of code re-use. RN never promise a single code base, but more like majority of the code base, which is still a big win.

Answer (score 9):

React Native for Android has just been released, Android folder will be creating along side with iOS folder upon creating a new project.

Answer (score 6):

Just another tip as NavigatorIOS was mentioned. Facebook are not really maintaining the code for NavigatorIOS. Instead they are focusing on Navigator.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. We're running it in production with about 5m registered users.

Some things are a little behind iOS but catching up quickly. It's a good wagon to be on.

Answer (score 2):

React Native is designed so that you can deploy to both iOS and Android. There is a caveat, of course.

React Native has supported iOS for much longer, coming to Android only recently. So, there are some differences in terms of what is supported on each platform.

For example, if you place borders on Text, they will show up on iOS, but not on Android. In order to overcome this, you need to place a View around the Text, and apply a border to that. Luckily, React Native makes it easy to integrate separate stylesheets for each platform (or even platform-specific styling on a single stylesheet).

Support for Android is continuously evolving, so it will only be a matter of time before React Native for Android is on par with iOS. Nevertheless, this shouldn't deter you. In my experience, it's a great way to quickly develop for both platforms, and it does save some headaches.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to maintenance separate code base for android & ios. Actually you can use same code base for build android & ios. I recommend to read the react-native [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)(according to react-native version you are using) before using any inbuilt component in your code. 
Eg:- [TextInput](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html) component onKeyPress function supports for ios only.

if ur are using external lib check these lib support for both ios and android. 
Anyway you have to configure external lib separately(install) both android and ios.

hope this will helpful.