# React native - android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

What is the exact process for building a mobile app with react native? (What's the download process, etc. from scratch?).

I saw a few videos and read in a few blogs about react native, but these sources seem to use it in Xcode, or android studio. Is it possible to use the same JS code to deploy the app in both platform? If so, what's the process of doing that?

Also, once I finish making in app, what's the process for getting a signed APK for android, or a build for apple iOS? I know that the language used is Javascript, so would I have to somehow "link" react native to android studio and Xcode, then copy the JS code to develop the iOs/android version of the same app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native & Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297269/react-native-android)

Comment: Doesn't the [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297269/react-native-android) ask about web apps? Also, I want to know how to "link" react native with android studio/Xcode, and the process of deploying the actual builds/APK's.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.56/signed-apk-android official documentation for Android APK build. For iOS as I remember you have to use XCode and create a normal native application out of your source code: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?34616,HowTo%3A+Create+an+.ipa+file+from+XCode,

Comment: If it's what you searched for I will put this commend into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow these complete steps
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

The process for making signed APK for android and build for ios is same as we always done for native development.